# How to compare two calendars to check if the event happened today?

Tags: java

I have two calendars `calendarCurrent` and `calendarReceived`, how to check if they are on the same date (don't take hours, mins, sec into account)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PATTER, Locale.US);
String receivedStringDate = "2012-12-01T00:33:24.935Z";
sdf.parse(receivedStringDate, new ParsePosition(0));
calendarCurrent = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
calendarReceived = sdf.getCalendar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if their YEAR, MONTH and DATE fields are the same: [Calendar.get(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

Write your own `Calendar` comparator, for this implement interface `Comparator<Calendar>`

You can also use third party APIs like [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
Calendar.YEAR
Calendar.MONTH
Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH
```

Refer : http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html